# Can it be decided if a number is a prime number in O(1) time complexcity

Tags: time

Can anyone tell me a way of deciding a number is a prime in O(1)?

Asked me in a interview

Comment: This is nonsense. A large number N takes log(N) to read, much less decide if it is prime.

Answer (score 2):

You can't really find a way of deciding if a number is a prime in O(1) so I'll say that if there is a any limit, you could use a hash table just like Yanzhe Chen said. But it won't work if there is NO limit.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is not really if there is no limit. If there is one then simply use a table.

Answer (score 1):

If there is an range limit of such a query, you can use a hash table, else there is no way. One simple way is to store all the prime number in a table which key is the number itself and value is whether it is prime or not. Of course you must have a limit range of such a table.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have an infinite HashSet/similar containing all of the prime numbers, you can't. And you can't have one of those so, well, you can't.

[Some tests](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AKS_primality_test)  work in polynomial time.